# powers in the group of integers modulo n - Zn

Tags: group-theory, modular-arithmetic

Let $\mathbb Z_n$ be the group of integers modulo $n$, and define power of elements in the group as following: $$[a]^{[b]} = \left[a^b\right].$$

I need to prove that this definition of power is not well defined, because it can lead to $\left[a ^ b\right]$ not equal to $\left[a^{b + n}\right] or \left[(a + n)^b\right]$.

I found one example in $\mathbb Z_3$, where $$[2]^{[1]} = [2^1] = [2] \ne [2]^{[1]} = [2]^{[4]} = [2^4] = [1].$$ But most of the other examples I tried fit well into the definition and do not cause inequalities.

What is the rule that decides which $a$, $b$ fit into the definition and which $a$, $b$ do not?

Thank you!

Comment: Use mathjax to make your post more readable :)

Comment: [Here's a MathJax tutorial](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020/104041) :)

Comment: Please consider using MathJax. To familiarize yourself with math Jax you can use the link above. This is considered a standard I'm this site.

Comment: sorry guys, new to this website :) I will definitely use it next time!

Comment: I've added MathJax to your post - you can take a look at the changes that have been made so you're familiar with it for your next question!

Comment: @kipf Thank you!

Comment: You began by talking about the group $Z_n$ (which is a group with the addition modulo $n$) but then used mainly multiplication modulo $n$. You probably should talk about the *ring* of integers modulo $n$.

Answer (score 1):

This is a good question. The thing is the power does not behave like addition or multiplication. You have several cases:

- $a \in \mathbb{Z}/n\mathbb{Z}$ is nilpotent, i.e. $\exists k \in \mathbb{N}$ such that $a^k = 0$. It is the case for $[2] \in \mathbb{Z}/4\mathbb{Z}$.
  Then you have necessarily some $k \in \mathbb{N}$ such that $k = 1 \mod{n}$, which means $a^k = 0$ and $a^1 = a$ which is a different result if $a \neq [0]$.
  Thus this doesn't work.
- If $a$ is not nilpotent (like if $n$ is prime). You can chose $a$ invertible (but non nilpotent does not mean invertible, e.g. $[2]$ \in $\mathbb{Z}/6\mathbb{Z}$).
  Then $a \in \mathbb{Z}/n\mathbb{Z}^\times$ a group of order $\varphi(n)$. Necessarily you have $a^{\varphi(n)} = [1]$. Then for such elements you have $a^k = a^{k + m \varphi(n)}$, so the power is well defined but not for $\mathbb{Z}/n\mathbb{Z}$, but for $\mathbb{Z}/\varphi(n)\mathbb{Z}$. You can even replace $\varphi(n)$ by the order of $a$.

Answer (score 0):

You can explicitly expand the two options you mentioned -

$$a^{b+n} = a^b a^n,$$
$$(a+n)^b = \sum_{k=0}^b\frac{n!}{k!(n-k)!}a^kn^{b-k}.$$

Therefore, for the first term to be $a^b$, we mut have $a^n=1$, and for the second to be $a^b$ we must have $$\sum_{k=0}^{b-1}\frac{n!}{k!(n-k)!}a^kn^{b-k} = 0.$$

Since every element of the sum is $0$ modulo $n$, (since $k < b$), the second condition always holds. The first may or may not hold, depending on the values of $a, n$.

Comment: Use `$$y=x^2$$` for $$y=x^2$$ and `$y=x^2$` for $y=x^2$.

Comment: thank you very much! really helpful.

Comment: Correct, thanks! I edited my comment.